# View the response body of a COMET event with Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: scala, playframework, google-chrome-devtools, comet

Is it currently possible to view the body of the message being sent by a COMET event using Chrome Developer tools? I'm simply looking at COMET Clock sample here by Play Framework - http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Samples. When I enable the developer tools and go to the event-stream object, I can only see the request and response headers. No body or message can be viewed anywhere. Is this currently even possible? Nothing shows up under WebSockets, but I'm fairly sure this example is not using WebSockets, so that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not possible for HTTP streaming (which I think it is your case) as March 2014 (hopefully they change this in the future)

Google Devtools only shows the response when the connection is closed. 
In the case of web-sockets you do see live data.

But! modern versions of Firebug can show live data streaming. So I recommend you get Firefox and install the Firebug addon.

((Ahh firebug, it used to be all we had. Poor forgotten guy. But it still has nice things Chrome lacks!))

Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

You can inspect the response from any HTTP request using the DevTools [Network tab](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network#http_response). To make finding your Comet request easier, select the XHR filter button at the bottom of the Network tab panel. You may need to reload the page after opening the Network tab to refresh the list of requests. Sometime it is necessary to switch back and forth between the All and XHR filters to see new requests that have been initiated since selecting the XHR filter. Once you have identified the request item, click to select it. On the right panel choose 
Response from the taps at the top